# What are effective methods/tools to aid in debugging Java?

Tags: java, debugging

In PHP, I always just `var_dump`'d everything. In Java, when I'm debugging a program such as implement BFS. I am finding it extremely difficult to just `System.out.println` everything, especially when there are tons of loops.

I think I have a poor practice and workflow. I could use JUnit, but when I have to go through every step to make sure every little thing is true or false and if variables are setting properly and checking each and every section, I am not sure if JUnit is any faster than `System.out.println`.

I am sure I might be doing something wrong, so I wanted to ask the community for better practices.

Edit: I use Eclipse, just to let you guys know. However, I don't know how to utilize every aspect of it. I just write code, debug, and compile. Sometimes JUnit, when I am required to use it.

Comment: For debugging, use a debugger. For unit testing, use a unit testing framework. They're different things.

Comment: @pst Thanks for title change!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you start with ["Using the eclipse debugger"](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html)

Comment: It isn't that he should use eclipse for debugging (I personally prefer Intellij). It is that the videos present the notion of a debugger and its use which is what Doug asked about

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just printing debug information to the console, use a logging system like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html).

This offers dynamic loglevels and logging can be send to a set of rotating files through configuration. (I.e. log lots of data while developing, and only log the errors in production without having to change the course code.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still quite new to Java coding, but I've found it very helpfully to create an `Debug` class and calling it instead of doing a lot of `System.out.println` calls.

My debuging class look something like this..

## Debug.java

```
   public class Debug {
    private static boolean debugActive = true;
    public static void setDebug(boolean debug) {
        Debug.debugActive = debug;
    }

    public static void print(String str) {
        if (debugActive) {

            StackTraceElement[] stacktrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
            StackTraceElement e = stacktrace[2];
            String methodName = e.getMethodName();

            System.out.print("[" + e + "]");
            System.out.print(" => " + str);
            System.out.println(" <= ");

        }
    }

    public static void print(int x) {
        print(x + "");
    }
}
```

So calling it from the program

## DbIniParser.java ..

```
   [...]
    Debug.print(DB_User);
    Debug.print(DB_Pass);
    Debug.print(database);
    Debug.print(host);
    Debug.print(port);
    [...]
```

## Main program.

```
Debug.setDebug(true);
DbIniParser ini = new DbIniParser();
ini.readFile();
Debug.setDebug(false);
```

This provides a output as..

## Console output

```
[hospitalcase.DbIniParser.readFile(DbIniParser.java:35)] => hjess <= 
[hospitalcase.DbIniParser.readFile(DbIniParser.java:36)] => password <= 
[hospitalcase.DbIniParser.readFile(DbIniParser.java:37)] => myFunnyDatabase <= 
[hospitalcase.DbIniParser.readFile(DbIniParser.java:38)] => localhost <= 
[hospitalcase.DbIniParser.readFile(DbIniParser.java:39)] => 3306 <=
```

By using a class itself the output could be changed to be a log file or something else.

Please mind I've only done programming in 3 months so this way might not be optimal, but I've found it quite useful instead for doing `System.out.print` every time.

Comment: What you are doing is very similar to what logging frameworks do. Consider checking, for example, [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)

Comment: You should have a look at [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/), certainly the most used logging framework in Java. It provides everything you have in your Debug class, and a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use an IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse. They come with a debugger.